# Automated Way to Migrate a Wordpress.com site to Wordpress.org

Tags: wordpress, wordpress.com

I was recently appointed to maintain a small news site. My managers want me to move their Wordpress.com site to Wordpress.org. I am considering using the theme “[Newspaper 7](http://demo.tagdiv.com/newspaper/)”. Our site has about 3,000 articles on it. Each has a few pictures that are stored on Wordpress.com’s servers. Is there an automated way to migrate all of these articles to a new theme that probably has a different tag/categorical system?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such automated way to migrate.

You need to manually export the content through WordPress export tool from WordPress.com and import to your self-hosted WordPress site.

Or you could pay [USD $129](https://en.support.wordpress.com/guided-transfer/) to WordPress.com and they will help you to transfer your site to one of their recommended hosting partners.

Comment: How do they accomplish doing it in a day if there isn't an automated way to do it?

Comment: The WordPress export tool can export your site content in a XML format file and download the image files from WordPress.com when import content to your self-hosted site. So, there is no big differences if your site has 10 articles or 3000 articles. For an experienced engineer, half day should be enough.